# Can not get the error message in the spring form

Tags: spring, spring-mvc

I am woring on an Spring Web application with the CURD operation for the Entity `Department`, this is the handler for processing the submit of a new `Department`:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public String addSubmit(@Valid Department department, BindingResult result,SessionStatus status) {
    if (result.hasErrors()) {
        return "department/add";
    } else {
        departmentService.save(department);
        status.setComplete();
        return "redirect:/departments/" + department.getId();
    }
}
```

Model:

```
@Entity
public class Department extends BaseNamedEntity {
    @NotNull
    @NotEmpty
    private String description;
    ...
}
```

And the form:

```
<form:form method="post" action="${fmURL}" class="form-horizontal" commandName="department">
    <form:hidden path="id"/>
    <spring:bind path="name">
        <div class="control-group ${status.error ? 'error' : ''}">
            <label class="control-label">Name</label>
            <div class="controls">
                <form:input path="name"/>
                <span class="help-inline">${status.errorMessage}</span>
            </div>
        </div>
    </spring:bind>
<form:form>
```

However, once I submit the form with empty field, normally, the errorMessage should be displayed and the related `div` should be add a class with `error`, however I can not found the error message.

What's going on?

BTW, the example is derive from [Spring-petclinic project](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-petclinic/blob/master/src/main/java/org/springframework/samples/petclinic/web/OwnerController.java).

Comment: And why do you think there would be a `status` object? There isn't any unless you use the old `spring:bind` tag.

Comment: I know that I have not expose the `status` by myself, but I am not sure if spring did that for me, I just followed the `spring-petclinic` project.

Comment: @M.Deinum: I am sorry I have missed the `spring:bind` tab in the `springpetclinic` project, however even I update my controller and view, the error is still invisible, check my update.

Comment: Do expressions even work? What do you see in the rendered page as a result?

Comment: Nothing, just the form without err message

Comment: I meant in the source of the rendered page, not the browser but the underlying source. I suspect that your expressions aren't evaluated.

Comment: http://imgbin.org/images/21806.png They are normal html codes.

Comment: You are missing a `@ModelAttribute` next to the `@Valid` on your method argument.

Comment: I added that, but have no affect. And the `spring-petclinic` project does not use the `ModelAttribute` also.

Comment: Well they should :). The code yuo added is the actual code? You aren't doing a redirect insetad of a normal view rendering? Do you have a `@MOdelAttribute` annotated method? Enable debug logging and see what happens on the server.

Comment: In fact I mean that the `spring-pet` project does not use the `ModelAttribute` but they can get the error message. And I have checked the debug message, and found that the error message are sent back to the client.

Comment: Doesn't matter they should still use it, but that is another discussion. Make sure that there isn't a redirect or something else clearing things. After a redirect there is no model anymore.

Comment: I am sure there is no redirect, since after I submit and hit the refresh button of the browser I will get a confim dialog which ask me if I would send the post data again. Maybe I should post the full code tomorrow.